# why does next-auth give TypeError Cannot destructure property 'manager' of 'connection' as it is null?

Tags: mongoose, next.js, next-auth

This error happens when I connect to mongo atlas but when I use a local database it works fine. Check out the db connection image and terminal error for more info.

dbconnect.ts

```js
import mongoose from "mongoose";

export default async function dbConnect() {

    if (mongoose.connection.readyState >= 1) {
        return;
    }

    return mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL as string, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        useFindAndModify: false,
        useCreateIndex: true,
    });
}
```

This is the error I am getting below

```
Top-level use of w, wtimeout, j, and fsync is deprecated. 
Use writeConcern instead.
(node:4052) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'MongoError' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
Top-level use of w, wtimeout, j, and fsync is deprecated. Use writeConcern instead.
[next-auth][error][adapter_connection_error]
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#adapter_connection_error MongoError: Authentication failed.
    at MessageStream.messageHandler (C:\Users\Sebas\Documents\ProdCode\fitur\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:268:20)
    at MessageStream.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at processIncomingData (C:\Users\Sebas\Documents\ProdCode\fitur\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:144:12)
    at MessageStream._write (C:\Users\Sebas\Documents\ProdCode\fitur\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:42:5)
    at writeOrBuffer (internal/streams/writable.js:358:12)
    at MessageStream.Writable.write (internal/streams/writable.js:303:10)
    at TLSSocket.ondata (internal/streams/readable.js:719:22)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:309:12)
    at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:284:9)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:223:10)
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23) {
  ok: 0,
  code: 8000,
  codeName: 'AtlasError'
}
[next-auth][error][session_error]
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#session_error TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'manager' of 'connection' as it is null.
```

Comment: @sebastian I answered below. Please take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66533184/why-does-next-auth-give-typeerror-cannot-destructure-property-manager-of-conn/68112015#68112015
I solved this same error in my application. Hope it will help you to identify and solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can check by `console.log(process.env.MONGO_URL)` inside the `function dbConnect()` to see whether it is undefined or not.

This is because I have the same problem with this same error message

> MongoError: Authentication failed

I required `dotenv` in **app.js** file but when app starts, it will start with **bin/www** file. So I put the below code in **bin/www** file.

```
// Config
require('dotenv').config({
  path: './config/keys.env'
})
```

In **dbConnection.js** file,

```
// Connecting database
module.exports.connectDB = async () => {
  try {
    await mongoose
      .connect(process.env.MONGODB_URL, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        useFindAndModify: false,
        useCreateIndex: true,
      })
      .then(() => console.log("MongoDB connected..."));
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};
```

And surprisingly everything works fine for me after that.

So you should check first. If that is undefined, it means your `env` file processes after `bdConnect()` executes.